# RTMP Connection Timeout in Python

Tags: python, nginx, streaming, rtmp

we created a RTMP server using NGINX and have a camera that is streaming video to that server.  We have a python program that should connect to the RTMP server and then display the video on the computer.  When we run the program we keep getting the below error:

RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 110 (Connection timed out)

I found a RTMP url on that was used for testing the code and it works but our RTMP server doesnt.  Does anyone know of any settings that need to be set to be able to get passed this error?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would check your firewall, TCP port 1935 needs to be open.